# Sticky footer works on all but one page

Tags: css, sticky-footer

Page is [here](http://www.jcwebandgraphic.com/work.html)

I am using a sticky footer, which works fine everywhere but my portfolio page. The gallery is relatively positioned, and is overflowing from it's parent div. The footer is sticking to the bottom of the parent, rather than the page.

Help? Preferably in a way where I don't have to rewrite all my code?

Answer (score 3):

Please try this one i hope it will helpful to you.

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
header {
    background: #fff;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
}
.content2 {
    clear: both;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 70%;
}
.gallery {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
#footer-block {
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by coding body and html to 110% height, footer wrapper to 100% height, and adding page wrapper with 100% height.